# Running from Bash getenv is not defined

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to run my program from the bash.

I am getting the following error:

> File "/Users/tai/Desktop/FlashY/flashy/sniffer/awsAccess.py", line 8, in 
>       aws_access_key_id=getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY');
>
> NameError: name 'getenv' is not defined

I have the exports saved in bash_profile. I checked and found them all to be there:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

My code in awsAccess looks like this:

```
#aswAccess holds the names of the bash environment set keys.
#used by other classes to create a connection to aws
aws_access_key_id=getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY');
aws_secret_access_key=getenv('AWS_SECRET_KEY');
aws_dynamo_region=getenv('DYANAMO_REGION')
```

The key name (not sure what to call this) matches in my bash_profile.

I was looking at an example that used getenv and it worked fine. I'm working on latest osx, python 2.7, running from bash shell, etc. Unsure of what's going wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getenv` is a function in the os module, you can't call it alone unless you import it appropriately.

So either at the top of your file put:

```
import os
```

and change the function call to `os.getenv()`. Or, import the function stand-alone:

```
from os import getenv
```

Comment: ah that was silly of me, thank you! Strange the example didn't have that maybe it was designed as pseudocode :S

Comment: @TaiHirabayashi No problem. If it still doesn't work make sure you've run `source ~/.bash_profile` or opened a new shell.